# Importing libraries with parameters writen in Python to Robot framework in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, robotframework

I'm using Eclipse for writing automated tests in Robot framework.
I have a simple library that accepts one argument:

```
class TestVar:   

def __init__(self, var):
    self._var = var   

def get_var(self):           
    return self._var
```

Then, I import the library in my test suite:

```
Library           TestVar    42
```

When I run this test:

```
Test    
${var2}=    Get Var   
Log     ${var2}
```

I get 42 as expected.

But the problem is Eclipse doesn't want to add the library into red.xml, nor wants to recognise it in any way:
[Eclipse fails to import a library with parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moqKm.png)

When I change my library to a library that doesn't expect any parameter, Eclipse works just fine.

It must be something with Eclipse setting that I have no idea about.

I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Have you tried making the parameter optional, so that it can be imported with or without a parameter?

Comment: Thank you, it worked like magic :)
Also, it seems that Eclipse cares about what I put into the constructor, so doing:

def __init__(self, *var):
        self._var = var[0]

is just as bad as my initial post, and Eclipse will not allow it. But doing just:

def __init__(self, *var):
        self._var = var

makes the trick. What's also possible (probably better than the first one):

def __init__(self, var=5):
        self._var = var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical solution for this is to make the arguments to your library optional. That way tools like libdoc or eclipse can import the library without arguments, while still allowing you to pass arguments when running the test.

Comment: Yes, just did that and it worked, thank you for answering my question :)

Comment: @puzzle, can you mark this as your answer. That way others wil recognize it as the right thing to look at.